# Normalization of schemes which are not reduced

Tags: algebraic-geometry

One usually defines normalization for reduced schemes. Is it possible to do it also for non-reduced ones?

We know that to any scheme we can associate a reduced one. Is then sufficient to work on this reduced scheme to get the normalization of the initial one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Stacks Project, it is wiser to consider the normalization only for a scheme $X$ such that every quasi-compact open subset of $X$ has finitely many irreducible components. Then by [lemma 28.50.2](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035O), the normalization $\widetilde{X}\to X$ factors through $X_{red} \to X$ and $\widetilde{X} \to X_{red}$ is the normalization of $X_{red}$.

Comment: Ok so for example if we put also noetherianity condition on our scheme, then this should work?

Comment: Yes, and local noetherianity is even enough because then any quasi-compact open subset is noetherian.